# How to batch long process in serial using RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a big list of strings that needs to be checked against remote API.

```
Observable.from(List<String> strings) // let's say the `strings` has > 5000 items
   .buffer(50) // splitting the strings into 50-sized chunks, it returns Observable<List<String>> (fast)
   .flatMap((strings) -> {
       // checkPhoneNumbers is a network call using Retrofit's RxJava (slow)
       return mSyncApi.checkPhoneNumbers(strings);
   })
   .reduce( ... ) // aggregate all checking results
   .subscribe( ... );
```

The problem is `buffer()` seems to emit `List<String>` too fast that all of multiple `.checkPhoneNumbers()` get executed almost in the same time. **What I would like to achieve is to enqueue `.checkPhoneNumbers()` to better support devices with slow connection.**

Throttling the emitted `List<String>` by predefined time interval doesn't make sense since it will be a disadvantage for devices with lightning fast connection. 
I have tried RxJava's `serialize()` right after the `flatMap()` but it doesn't seems make any difference (although I don't know if it's the right use of `serialize`).

Any alternative approaches appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `flatMap(Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> func, int maxConcurrent)`?

Comment: @zsxwing cannot find that method signature. is it a new API?

Comment: btw, I'm using `io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0`

Comment: It's added in RxJava 1.0.6. I think it's compatible with RxAndroid 0.24.0.

Comment: @zsxwing I've just checked Maven central, unfortunately RxAndroid 0.24.0 is still using RxJava 1.0.4

Comment: You can add RxJava to your dependencies and specify the version explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @zsxwing suggested, I think the `maxConcurrent` overload is what you're looking for if you're trying to limit the concurrency occurring inside `flatMap`.

For example: https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/a0350776a595fd6e3810#file-parallelexecution-java-L78

```
private static void flatMapBufferedExampleAsync() {
    final AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger();
    Observable.range(0, 500000000)
            .doOnNext(i -> total.incrementAndGet())
            .buffer(100)
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("emit " + i))
            .flatMap(i -> {
                return Observable.from(i).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).map(item -> {
                    // simulate computational work
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        return item + " processed " + Thread.currentThread();
                    });
            }, 2 /* limit concurrency to 2 */) // <--- note argument here
           .toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("total emitted: " + total.get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't find that `flatMap` variant in my latest `RxAndroid` dependency. However I just found that the easiest way is by replacing `flatMap` with `concatMap`, it basically subscribe to the observables sequentially one by one after the previous one completes. It's not as flexible as `flatMap(func1, maxConcurrent)` though.

Comment: @akhyar `flatmap(func1, maxConcurrent)` landed in RxJava 1.0.6, but the newest RxAndroid (0.24.0) uses 1.0.4.  You can make RxAndroid use a newer version of RxJava by declaring it manually: 
`compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'` and then `compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.9'`... Works well for me (no instabilities in RxAndroid)