# Observable emitter generates too much pressure for HystrixCommands

Tags: java-8, rx-java, observable, hystrix

I have an Observable that emits file lines (many GBs read from GCS).

```
return StringObservable.byLine(
    Observable.using(
        () -> storage.get(blobId).reader(),
            reader -> Observable.create(
                    new OnSubscribeReadChannel(reader, 64 * 1024)
                ),
            ReadChannel::close
    )
)
```

Each line results in multiple (many in some cases) calls to various DBs, all wrapped in Hystrix commands. Obviously the lines eventually overwhelm the Hystrix commands, circuits start opening and everyone has a bad day.

This is roughly what I'm doing:

```
readLinesFromCloudStorageFile.readLines(blobInfo.getBlobId()))
            .map(this::deserializeLine)
            .flatMap(this::addDataToObjectFromSomeDb)
            .flatMap(this::writeObj)
            .map(Set::size)
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
            .toBlocking().single()
```

Is there a way I can apply some back-pressure, or limit the number of lines being processed at a time or something?

Comment: maybe `maxConcurrent` helps, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28946783/5515060).

Comment: That's interesting. Would using `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` effectively serialize the writes?

Comment: From the output's perspective, `concatMap` and `flatMap(maxConcurrency=1)` looks the same. From the input's perspective, `concatMap` fetches at least 1 item upfront even if there is 1 inner source being processed whereas `flatMap(1)` asks for the next inner source only if the last one completed.

Comment: are you using RxJava 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: RxJava 1.x - Hystrix is locked to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER`

```
BUFFER
Buffers (unbounded) all onNext calls until the downstream can consume them.
```

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/index.html?rx/Emitter.BackpressureMode.html

Comment: The issue with this is that the buffer could become many GB, at some point the reader has to be throttled.